# How to edit different fields in discord embed?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to edit an embed by adding the user's name into the embed field. It works, however if there are more than one field it edits all of them. User can add and remove embeds using a command so I don't know what names these fields have.

I want it so that users can react by emojis and depending on which emoji they use, it adds their name to a field.

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    msg = await bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id).fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    if not msg.author.bot:
        return
    if not msg.embeds:
        return
    embed1 = msg.embeds[0]
    embed_dict = embed1.to_dict()
    for field in embed_dict["fields"]:
        field["value"] += f" {payload.member.name},"
    embed2 = discord.Embed.from_dict(embed_dict)
    await msg.edit(embed=embed2)
```

Comment: What is the intended behavior? Do you only want to edit 1 field (first one, second one, last one, etc)?

Comment: @EricJin I want to edit one field depending on emoji used in reaction. So if I react with, let's say laughing emoji, the first field is edited. If I use crying emoji, second field.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through *every field*, but only one of them needs to be changed.

You can check the [`PartialEmoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=raw_reaction_add#discord.PartialEmoji), which can be both standard or custom, used in the reaction through `payload.emoji`.

```py
    embed_dict = embed1.to_dict()

    to_modify = {
        discord.PartialEmoji.from_str(''): 0,
        discord.PartialEmoji.from_str(''): 1
        # etc
    }
    emoji_used = payload.emoji  # returns PartialEmoji containing the emoji
    number = to_modify[emoji_used]  # select field to modify
    embed_dict[number]["value"] += f" {payload.member.name},"

    embed2 = discord.Embed.from_dict(embed_dict)
```

Comment: It results in KeyError: 0 or KeyError: 1. I tried to fix it, but it looks like "number" has to be somewhere else.